# Cannot redirect correctly with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, pantheon

I have a blog in a website that I want to redirect.

For example this URL https://example.com/blog/june-2021/name-of-blog-post should redirect to https://example2.com/blog/june-2021/name-of-blog-post

There are hundreds of blog posts so I can't use an array to redirect them one by one.

I'm using Pantheon as the host. I added the script to settings.php.

Currently everything from example.com goes to example2.com, so it's not working correctly.

Here's my script:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
$blog = $uri_segments[0];
$post_date = $uri_segments[1];
$post_name = $uri_segments[2];

if ((stripos($url, "/blog/") === 0) && (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently'); header("Location: https://example2.com".$blog.$post_date.$post_name);
  if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
    newrelic_name_transaction("redirect");
  }
exit(); }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stripos` only takes 3 arguments and use `!== false` instead.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! So should I use `strstr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `/blog/` by checking that it is found `!== false` anywhere in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
if ((stripos($url, "/blog/") !== false) && (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
```

Or check to see if it is found at the first `0` position of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
if ((stripos($url, "/blog/") === 0) && (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
```

**Notes**:

1. `stripos` only takes three arguments and you only need the first two.
2. `Location` header should consist of a *single absolute URI* like `https://example2.com/blog/june-2021/name-of-blog-post`, so you might look at the other `$_SERVER` variables to construct one.

Comment: Can the location header have those variables inside? Please take a look at my updated code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but that's looks like it will be the same as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: It looks correct but is the same.  Echo it and see what it is and if it works.